# Проблема сборки проекта asp net с Docker

Tags: linux, asp.net, docker, asp.net-core

Не собирается проект с поддержкой Docker. В окне вывода появляется следующая информация.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Погуглив, я скачал пакет с файлами Linux. Попробовал закинуть эти файлы в папку, которая указана в выводе.

При запуске новой сборки - эти файлы удаляются(выполняется 3 строка в окне вывода), а если закинуть файлы во время сборки - то сборка выполнится и проекта будет запущен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, скачав два архива с файлами linux.

https://vsdebugger.azureedge.net/vsdbg-17-2-10518-1/vsdbg-linux-x64.zip
https://vsdebugger.azureedge.net/vsdbg-17-2-10518-1/vsdbg-linux-musl-x64.zip

Вместо `17-2-10518-1` можете вставить свою версию.

Первый архив необходимо разархивировать в C:\Users<PCNAME>\vsdbg\vs2017u5 (если папки vs2017u5 нет - создать). Второй архив - C:\Users<PCNAME>\vsdbg\vs2017u5\linux-musl-x64